# Very slow Update Statement

Tags: sql, database, performance, select, sql-update

I have the following update statement which runs several times and is very slow (20+ seconds). Any recommendations on how to improve its performance?

```
    update acc_item 
set means_pay_no = m_pay_no
where acc_item_no in (select distinct(acc.acc_item_no) 
                      from acc_item acc, (select accm.acc_item_no acc1,accm.acc_item_no_2 acc2
                                            from acc_item_match accm,acc_payment_item accp
                                            where accp.acc_payment_no=pay_no
                                            and (accm.acc_item_no = accp.acc_item_no or accm.acc_item_no_2 = accp.acc_item_no))
                      where acc.acc_item_no = acc1
                      or acc.acc_item_no = acc2)                    
and reversed_to_acc_item_no is null;
```

Comment: Show your execution plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
update acc_item 
set means_pay_no = m_pay_no
where exists (select 1
              from acc_item acc 
              where exists 
               (select 1
                from acc_item_match accm,acc_payment_item accp
                where accp.acc_payment_no=pay_no
                and accp.acc_item_no in (accm.acc_item_no, accm.acc_item_no_2)
                and acc.acc_item_no in (accm.acc_item_no, accm.acc_item_no_2)
                ) and acc.acc_item_no = acc_item.acc_item_no
              )
and reversed_to_acc_item_no is null;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried it but it seems to have something missing. I am having difficulty following the logic. Is there something missing above?

Comment: @user2706266 I tried to write it again, hopefully I have not forgotten anything this time

Comment: Thank you very much for your help it seems to be working fine with excellent performance

Answer (score 1):

How about insert  statement query in temp table?

```
select distinct(acc.acc_item_no) into #temptbl 
from acc_item acc, (select accm.acc_item_no acc1,accm.acc_item_no_2 acc2
from acc_item_match accm,acc_payment_item accp
where accp.acc_payment_no=pay_no
and (accm.acc_item_no = accp.acc_item_no or accm.acc_item_no_2 = accp.acc_item_no))
where acc.acc_item_no = acc1
or acc.acc_item_no = acc2


update acc_item 
set means_pay_no = m_pay_no
where acc_item_no in (select * from #temptbl)                    
and reversed_to_acc_item_no is null;
```